Solana transactions not being sent solana web3.js
I am using solana web3.js to send transactions from my console and out of nowhere the code has stopped working even though it did the job previously.
async function sendTransaction(secretKey: string, amount: number, to: string) {
  try {
    const secretKeyArray = new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(secretKey));
    const account = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKeyArray);
    const toPubkey = new PublicKey(to);

    const { lamportsPerSignature } = (
      await solanaConnection.getRecentBlockhash("confirmed")
    ).feeCalculator;

    const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
      web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: account.publicKey,
        toPubkey,
        lamports: amount - lamportsPerSignature,
      })
    );

    const signature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      solanaConnection,
      transaction,
      [account]
    );

    log(`Fees of ${amount} lamports sent to account ${to}`);

    return signature;
  } catch (error) {
    const err = error as Error;
    console.log(err.message);
    log(`No transaction for ${amount} to ${to}`);
  }
}

I keep getting the error -
Signature 2xznU4yxXNygshK3ENDLdMi2LYsE3miqBDmFiz4SHzq8Xu7skn5xbkY3xc21sAeFghR7PuANtLrLPnS9u8mtYvnR has expired: block height exceeded.
No transaction for 135000000 to ELMXLPCtKjDVSTgNXdHBM7kHhC9yUzxBZYpmGfLsaGVC
Signature 4iCzWfKnLDQ2hYrufG3XVeyebq86v1tEjTbo93JHFXkwo1NeuVzRpG89sJEWHahPFtj46uUm153mNk8QN9Hucbzd has expired: block height exceeded.
No transaction for 135000000 to JAefeLFopjVGnFbwRbs29PEbmHNzWMpSsq5dE7cz2Evy
Signature 4WnXo96zTU9vZJY7NN2mdyX2n7AYNZTCyPzC3fNrn9UJULsuHbuBioWFw9kvYyCMVNTEDJVUHhtHu7mYaJd17wUd has expired: block height exceeded.
No transaction for 180000000 to Cd4qPLh7UAfKog5EyHv7ZXPyPCWuuyWbqk3LxRzpC1u4

How can this be fixed?

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?

Try adding priority fee and compute units, Also currently solana network is congested around 75% of non voting transaction are getting failed. You can add retry mechanism also.

retry mechanism like? I do retry the transaction on each fail. how can priority fees and compute units be added. It's super annoying cause a good amount of SOL is stuck in my accounts.

const transaction = new Transaction();
const modify_cu = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
  units: 100000,
});
const priority_fee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
  microLamports: 10 * 1000000,
});
transaction.add(modify_cu);
transaction.add(priority_fee);

somthing like this https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/how-to-use-priority-fees

what should the ideal value for compute units and priority fees be in the current scenario? because rn I get failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Computational budget exceeded or failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x1 if I try to increase the compute units
